# how to fetch api(POST) with header in react native app

Tags: json, api, react-native, http-headers, fetch-api

I am trying to put three params in my post request to particular api but i didn't get the response as i expected. API works fine in my Postman but i am not sure about my fetching method in my react native app i am new to this so i don't know how to put headers in my api request i followed some docs but didn't get much please have a look and answer my question.

```
 constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            detail: ''
        }
    }

    ComponentDidMount(){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('mobile_number','8615351655')
        data.append('mobile_country_code','+21')
        data.append('rec_name','Shantanu Talwaar')
    }
    fetchData = async() => {
        fetch('http://link.com/link/',
        {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers:{
                 //this what's exactly look in my postman
                'Authorization': 'Token 97a74c03004e7d6b0658dfdfde34fd6aa4b14ddb;
            },
            body: this.data
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
                alert(responseJson.detail)
        }).catch((error) => {
            alert('error')})}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Button onPress = {this.fetchData} title = "fetch"/>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Fetched data displays below</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.detail}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is the result i am having right now in my alert box: "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a ' missing after your token.

```
'Authorization': 'Token 97a74c03004e7d6b0658dfdfde34fd6aa4b14ddb;
```

And as it is a JSON Object you should remove the semi-colon

So, the final code will be

```
'Authorization': 'Token 97a74c03004e7d6b0658dfdfde34fd6aa4b14ddb'
```

There is also another problem. The data declaration is not accessible from the fetch function. So you should do something like this.

```
fetchData = async() => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('mobile_number','8615351655')
    data.append('mobile_country_code','+21')
    data.append('rec_name','Shantanu Talwaar')

    fetch('http://link.com/link/',
    {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers:{
            //this what's exactly look in my postman
            'Authorization': 'Token 97a74c03004e7d6b0658dfdfde34fd6aa4b14ddb'
        },
        body: data
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson.detail)
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert('error')
    })
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the mistake. The statement inside catch() is getting executed. Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: I have fixed another problem in your code. About the auth token, you must see the API docs to see how it must be provided. What is the API?

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked man! please also upvote me. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

i think you can use "x-access-token" as header name for authentication token and place `Content-Type` too.

```js
fetchData = () => {
        fetch('http://link.com/link/',
        {
            method: 'POST', 
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'x-access-token': 'Token 97a74c03004e7d6b0658dfdfde34fd6aa4b14ddb'
            },
            body: this.data
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson.detail)
        }).catch((error) => {
            alert('error')})
            }
```

Comment: I am sending formData , and receiving JSON as response. Do i need to make any changes to this code ?

Comment: now your fetchData method work fine what you need to do next depends upon you application requirement.
you can handle response data to show message to user about success/failed to post data.